# What is the name for this layout under Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know if this kind of layout is supported under Android and what is its name.

The description:
the application is revealed by default in a main view and a menu will appear when making a "swipe gesture" from the margins to the center of the screen; usually this layout has to offer some kind of callback or manage to stop the underlaying activity for the application so the user can use the menu without interfering with what he is doing with the application itself.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This could help you.... <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a sliding layout, [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is an example:

you can call it with:

```
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    sliding:viewAbove="@layout/YOUR_ABOVE_VIEW"
    sliding:viewBehind="@layout/YOUR_BEHIND_BEHIND"
    sliding:touchModeAbove="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:touchModeBehind="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
    sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
    sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/YOUR_SCALE"
    sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SHADOW"
    sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/YOUR_SHADOW_WIDTH" />
```

There is no built in function like that, so you have to use third party libraries

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality for this behavior.  You'll need to make it yourself.

Comment: There are a couple of third-party libraries for this sort of "ribbon", though I don't have any links handy at the moment.