# Collapsible sidebar with fluid twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I am looking for a CSS solution to create a button to toggle a sidebar on and off using twitter bootstrap.

I'd like one of those little icons people have on their webpage that looks like a pull tab when the sidebar is closed, and then follows the sidebar out when it is pulled - does this have a name?

I've created a toggleSidebar icon link to do this, but I have two problems:

1. I can't get it to float with the sidebar using float: left or display: inline-block
2. Fixed, it creates a column of it's own... I want it float on top of the main content.

The html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="sidebar" class="span3 scrollDiv" style="display: none;">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="span12">
      <!--Main content-->
    </div>
    <a id="toggleSidebar" href="#" class="toggles"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#toggleSidebar {
  /* float: left; */
  /* display:inline-block; */
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:45px;
  color:#779DD7;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
```

The javascript:

```
function sidebar(panels) {
  if (panels === 1) {
    $('#content').removeClass('span9');
    $('#content').addClass('span12 no-sidebar');
    $('#sidebar').hide();
  } else if (panels === 2) {
    $('#content').removeClass('span12 no-sidebar');
    $('#content').addClass('span9');
    $('#sidebar').show();
  }
}

$('#toggleSidebar').click(function() {
  if ($.asm.panels === 1) {
    $('#toggleSidebar i').addClass('icon-chevron-left');
    $('#toggleSidebar i').removeClass('icon-chevron-right');
    return sidebar(2);
  } else {
    $('#toggleSidebar i').removeClass('icon-chevron-left');
    $('#toggleSidebar i').addClass('icon-chevron-right');
    return sidebar(1);
  }
})
```

A working example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/dmyTR/

For the life in me, I can't find an example on the web - but here's a quick drawing of what I'm after:
[image: Pull Bar]

It's a bit like the effect @ http://simplerealtytheme.com/plugins/pullout-widgets/ - which looks like they're using a display: block; clear: both; and then positioning the pull tab absolutely within the div with a negative right position.

Comment: have you looked at jquery as an option, slideToggle if i am understanding your question correctly

Comment: Thanks although, I'm okay with the toggling - more looking for help on positioning the button that toggles.

Comment: Just two hints: CSS only supports the comment syntax `/* comment */` (unlike LESS, which you might be using) and the semicolon after the declaration of the `sidebar` function is unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a website with a similar effect? I have trouble understanding. Do you want something that always follows when you scroll, and when you click on it, slides out, like on Android/iPhone? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb

Comment: @Adam I am a little confused as to what you are asking. So questions: 1) Is your problem purely a CSS problem? Also could you make a really quick sketch of how it should look like in both states? Also if you could chat for a minute we could create a room here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ cheers!

Comment: @Trufa - I can't seem to find a working example on the web, but I do see this as a CSS problem.  Something with positioning things absolutely relative to a div container.  I've added a quick sketch to the question.

Comment: @Aktee - thanks - I found a link there to http://simplerealtytheme.com/plugins/pullout-widgets/ that is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this is what you want, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/dmyTR/36/show/).

Relevant code is this:

```
#content {
    float:left;
}

#mapCanvas img {
    max-width: none;
}

#maincont{
    margin-top: 42px;
}

#toggleSidebar {
    float:left;
    color:#779DD7;
    padding:2px 4px;
}

#sidebar{
    float:left;   
}
```

Please confirm that that was what you have in mind!

Answer (score 15):

Is this what you had in mind?

http://jsfiddle.net/dmyTR/37/

Basically, instead of .hide() and .show(); you animate its position.

```
  // to hide 
  $('#sidebar').animate({
        left: -180,
  });

  // to show
  $('#sidebar').animate({
        left: 20,
  });
```

I removed #sidebar from .container-fluid, because, well, it's not part of the container. I also put #toggleSidebar inside #sidebar.

Comment: I just accepted Trufa's before seeing this - but using the animate looks much better.  I'm not sure if I can get away with covering the google map, as I don't want to hide the zoom controls on the upper left of the map, but I think I can still float the map along side the sidebar.  I like putting the toggleSidebar inside sidebar... makes much more sense to me intuitively.  Thank you!

Comment: You're better off covering google maps than redrawing it every time someone clicks on your sidebar.

Comment: The redrawing performance is okay, as the tiles are cached locally and not re-downloaded... but it does shift the map.  A better approach might be to put this toolbar on the right, and then I can cover the google map with the toolbar without loosing anything important... it does look sexier to have it just zip over the map, and saves the re-calculation.  I'll look into that.

Comment: thank you very much for this sidebar, nice easy and bootstrap ready!

Comment: Can anyone explain why clicking the sidebar arrow automatically scrolls you to the top of the page?

Comment: @varatis It's because the link target is set to "#" which tends to scroll you to the top of the page.

Comment: dude, it's perfect solution without tons of code and external libraries! Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an animated side drawer I drew up requiring very little bootstrap modification:
http://zombiehippie.github.io/Side-drawer/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* this is container is moved to the side if class is added*/
    .side-collapse-container{
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        transition:left .4s;
    }
    /* toggled when navbar is out */
    .side-collapse-container.out{
        left:200px;
    }
    .side-collapse {
        /* need top to keep from overlapping fixed header*/
        top:50px;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:200px;
        position:fixed;
        overflow:hidden;
        /* transition animates the element */
        transition:width .4s;
    }
    /* toggled when navbar is in */
    .side-collapse.in {
        width:0;
    }
}
```

A fixed navbar using the styles of `.side-collapse` allows us to fix the bar to the edge of our screen.

Adding `.side-collapse-container` to the the container after the header allows that content to be shifted over on open.

Some script appends a click event to the `[data-toggle=]` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
    var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
    var sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');
    sideslider.click(function(event){
        $(sel).toggleClass('in');
        $(sel2).toggleClass('out');
    });
});
```

Look at the github page for the source html or jade.

HTML source
https://github.com/ZombieHippie/Side-drawer/tree/gh-pages