# Toggle sidebar in bootstrap3?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm trying to get a togglable sidebar:

No sidebar:

```
>> | Main text
   | goes here
```

With sidebar:

```
H1 << | Main text
H2    | goes here
```

(here is an example of the behaviour: http://pythonhosted.org/cloud_sptheme -- see the button on sidebar. It's not easy to use its code base, because it's not bootstrap-based)

I started from a working example which uses Bootstrap 2 and jQuery 1.8: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/dmyTR), [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604285/collapsable-sidebar-with-fluid-twitter-bootstrap), and tried to make it work on Bootstrap 3. Here's a code ([code on bootply](http://bootply.com/104837)):

javascript:

```
$.asm = {};
$.asm.panels = 1;

function sidebar(panels) {
    $.asm.panels = panels;
    if (panels === 1) {
        $('#content').removeClass('col-md-9');
        $('#content').addClass('col-md-12');
        $('#sidebar1').removeClass('show');
        $('#sidebar1').addClass('hide');
    } else if (panels === 2) {
        $('#content').removeClass('col-md-12');
        $('#content').addClass('col-md-9');
        $('#sidebar1').removeClass('hide');
        $('#sidebar1').addClass('show');
    }
}

$('#toggleSidebar').click(function() {
    if ($.asm.panels === 1) {
        $('#toggleSidebar').addClass('fa-backward');
        $('#toggleSidebar').removeClass('fa-forward');
        return sidebar(2);
    } else {
        $('#toggleSidebar').removeClass('fa-backward');
        $('#toggleSidebar').addClass('fa-forward');
        return sidebar(1);
    }
})
```

css:

```
#toggleSidebar {
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:45px;
  color:#779DD7;
  padding:2px 4px;
}

hide {
    display: none;
}

show {
    display: inherit;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 hide" id="sidebar1">
      <div id="sidebar" class="bs-sidebar nav bs-sidenav pre-scrollable" role="complementary">

        Toc goes here.

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" id="content">

      Main text goes here.

    </div>

  </div>
  <a id="toggleSidebar" href="#toggleSidebar1" class="fa fa-forward"</a>
</div>
```

**Edit**:

Off canvas is not what I need: it doesn't conserve the horizonatal space, it shifts the div to the right, and the div gets out of the screen. Chanding `col-md-9` to `col-md-12` and back -- is the best thing I can think of for a problem at hand. This should be simple javascript, which I'm not good at.

Comment: it looks like you are way over complicating it. forget how that or any site does it. simply call `.toggle()` on the sidebar div.

Comment: @Timmerz: can You develop a little working example on bootply?

Comment: you have two div's right? in the sidebar div place the collapse button, in the content div place the expand button. on click of either, call `.toggle` on the sidebar and hide the expand button when sidebar is on...add a little css. simple as that.

Comment: @Timmerz: seems to me that it's more or less the same methodology I tried above. Only that You propose using two buttons instead of one. I think the methodology is fine, and anyone experinced in debugging javascript could solve it in a moment.

Comment: except it's not working for you and you have a huge mess of addClass and removeClass and 1's and 2's. what is that? simplify, my friend. simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I solved it:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.asm = {};
    $.asm.panels = 2;

    $('#toggleSidebar').click(function(){
        if ($.asm.panels === 1) {
            $('#toggleSidebar span').attr({'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-backward'});
            $('#content').attr({'class': 'col-md-9'});
            $('#sidebar1').show();
            $.asm.panels = 2;
        } else {
            $('#toggleSidebar span').attr({'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-forward'});
            $('#content').attr({'class': 'col-md-12'});
            $('#sidebar1').hide();
            $.asm.panels = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

css:

```
#toggleSidebar {
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:45px;
  color:#779DD7;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar1">
      <div id="sidebar" class="bs-sidebar nav bs-sidenav pre-scrollable" role="complementary">

        Toc goes here.

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9" id="content">

      Main text goes here.

    </div>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="toggleSidebar" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span></button>
</div>
```

[Demo on bootply](http://bootply.com/105072).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a "off-canvas" sidebar. Here are 2 off-canvas Bootstrap examples that slide in from the left..

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/off-canvas-sidebar http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/facebook

Both example use media queries to detect the browser and place the sidebar accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/. It is an offcanvas example made by bootstrap itself.

I also love this article http://jasonweaver.name/lab/offcanvas/.