# Slide In and Slide Out animation for a layout

Tags: java, android, slide

I have a `LinearLayout, I am dynamically adding TextView, ImageView to that LinearLayout`, now I have added OnClickListener to these TextViews and ImageViews.

I have an arraylist which has 10 items in it, using a for loop I am getting each value and displaying, since it's quiz app I have next and previous buttons, when I click on that I am displaying items one by one from the arraylist.`Now I need slide In and slide Out animation to apply to this Linear Layout.`

I have seen this :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb)

and also I have tried this

```
slideIn = new TranslateAnimation(
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);

slideIn.setDuration(500);
slideOut = new TranslateAnimation(
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);

slideOut.setDuration(500);
```

But not working please help on this.

**EDIT:**

Problem: I have applied this to the linear layout but what happens is that when i click on next button current question will slide left and a blank screen then it will slide in and display next question, but I want as soon as the current question slides out it should be followed by next question.

Comment: How you applied this animation to your view?

Comment: yes buddy i have applied this to the linear layout but what happens is that when i click on next current question will slide left and a blank  screen then it will slide in and display next question, but i want as soon as the current question slides out it should be followed by next question

Comment: What about using a viewflipper and using inanimation and out animation?

Comment: @PassionateAndroiden i have tried that but since i have 10 or n no of items in the arraylist i cannot use viewflipper

Comment: How many activities are you using? Just one or more than one?

Comment: Use only two layouts in flipper and dynamically change contents of the currently invisible layout. When user clicks next, populate invisible layout and load it to front with animation.

Comment: @PassionateAndroiden if you dont mind ,can you give me any example ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your layouts are having identical content, create two layouts inside a view flipper. 
Load first view with data and show it. 
When user clicks next or previous, load next view with data and keep a flag to show that 2nd view is now visible and show it with animation.

Now onwards load the appropriate views with data based on the flag values and call shownext().

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    firstLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    secondLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);


    findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showPrevious();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnNext).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showNext();
        }
    });

}

private void showNext() {
    mainFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left));
    mainFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right));
    flip();
}

private void showPrevious() {
    mainFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right));
    mainFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left));
    flip();
}

private void flip() {
    if(isFirstVisible) {
        isFirstVisible = false;
        secondLayout.removeAllViews();
        secondLayout.addView(getTextView("Second"));
    } else {
        isFirstVisible = true;
        firstLayout.removeAllViews();
        firstLayout.addView(getTextView("First"));
    }
    mainFlipper.showNext();
}

private TextView getTextView(String txt) {
    TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
    txtView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    txtView.setText(txt);
    return txtView;
}
```

Comment: hey i tried in the way which you have told but now i am not able to remove view which i am dynamically adding, if i use removeallviews() then animation will not work..

Comment: yes yes finally after trying i have acheived it with View flipper ... thanks a lot.Now the question is how to increase the speed of animation that is slide in and slide out?

Comment: speed of animation can be increased by decreasing duration value in animation xml. Do you mean that?

Answer (score 4):

Use this xml in res/anim/

leftright.xml
This is for left to right animation:

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700"/>
   </set>
```

use this in your java code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
{
   public void run()
 {
   item[i].setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.leftright.xml));
   i=i+1;
   handler.postDelayed(this,5000);
 }
};handler.postDelayed(runnable,5000);
```

Comment: how will i apply the animation to a layout ? i cannot apply the animation to single item as it has to first get the values from the arraylist and then display

Comment: on next click `setContentView(R.layout.View2)` then do this inside your class `Intent iSecondLayout = new Intent(Activity.this,Activity.class);
Activity.this.startActivity(iSecondLayout);
Activity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.lefttoright, R.anim.righttoleft);`

Comment: call that activity again with changing layout on next button click.See the code.I am calling the same class again and again.

Comment: or as one guy said you can use viewflipper.

Comment: i can use view flipper but problem is the item to load from arraylist and also the i dont know how to manage with 2 layouts

Comment: just send me a screenshot of what you are trying to do and I can see what I can do