# Accordion SubMenu in the Slide Menu Drawer - Android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am trying to do the accordion Sub Menu for Android. For Example. I have slide menu (Sliding Drawer Menu - Facebook Like Menu) in the Sliding Drawer menu if i select any of the items i am trying to get the accordion submenu. This is what i tried.

```
    @Override
public void onSlideMenuItemClick(int itemId) {

    switch (itemId) {
    case R.id.item_one:
        Toast.makeText(this, "LSM Item one selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.item_two:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item two selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.item_fourteen:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item fourteen selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.item_fifteen:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item fifteen selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768498
and there are many android libraries 
And alson i recommend you see this post 
[Navigation Drawer (Google+ vs. YouTube)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb)