# Swipe to side panel with first panel partially visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't think these examples use viewpager, but visually they look a little like viewpager.

See Evernote's settings:

http://1.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/howto/evernote-screenshots-120524.jpg

And Pocket Casts' handheld control pane:

http://www.shiftyjelly.com/android/pocketcasts

Basically, a panel is swiped in from left, but the left edge of the previous panel is still visible.

So my question is, is this UI pattern featured in an example you have seen, or did these two make it out of whole cloth and now I have to, too?

Edit for posterity:

As of Google I/O 2013, this is now built into Android. They call it the Navigation Drawer: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Looks like this is probably the preferred library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu</s>

This library might help you out.  I think this is what you're trying to achieve.

**EDIT**

I've updated the link to another SlidingMenu library but as of 2015/09/16, **I wouldn't use the library referenced here anyway**.  Google has provided the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) in the v4 support library to achieve this.  Inside the drawer, for a more standard structured navigation, the design support library has also provided the [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) that can be placed inside the DrawerLayout and use standard menu  resource to inflate the items contained within.  This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586725) can help out with the details of the implementation.

Comment: Hey thanks! This is definitely putting me on the right track. Here's a link for future viewers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb

Comment: @frenziedherring This link is not working any more please correct the link