# Unable to open navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml

I try to implement a drawerLayout but I get a rendering problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:openDrawer="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the error that android provides me

```
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
```

I also add the property that you see
  android: layout_gravity = "start" or android: layout_gravity = "left", but the error continues, I also cleaned and rebuilt the project, I add an image of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVO8s.png)

Comment: Can you add the `java` code to your question?

Comment: have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586725/how-to-create-navigation-drawer-using-android-design-support-library/31825141

Comment: the problem is not java itself, that error appears in the xml, in design view

Comment: I have already solved it, it seems that the navigationView must exist to render something and it shows in the drawerLayout