# Swiping between screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to swipe between screens with finger touch like the image below.

[image]

And the second screen should not be streched to the all of the screen but just the left part.

thx.

Comment: I'd lookup viewPager or look at this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: your are looking for a drawer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/navigation-drawer-is-official-slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube

Comment: Have you read about Navigation Drawers? http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: take a look at this amazing sliding menu : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is called navigation drawer. A new official Android guideline on such design can be found at

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

and how to implement it at

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html