# drawer effect in web app

Tags: javascript, animation, web-applications, effects

I've been searching the web for a javascript version of the "drawer effect", like in [Navigation Drawer (Google+ vs. YouTube)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/navigation-drawer-google-vs-youtube) . I need it in my web app.

Many view transition like slide, pop and flip have been animated using javascript, but I found none for this drawer effect. Could someone kindly share a link?

Answer (score 0):

This library will do the work: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/.