# how to use navigation drawer with swipe tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to use Navigation drawer in Action Bar and below that I want to use Swipe  Tabs in single sherlock fragment. I want to open above sherlock fragment on the Item click of ListView.And Most Important think is that I want to open different swipe tab on the click of different Item in ListView.
thank in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer (Google+ vs. YouTube)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/navigation-drawer-google-vs-youtube).....it is not possible anyone to understand the requirement this way...pls do post pictorial representation to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library. Because Navigation Drawer with swipe tabs is really difficult and as far as I know many developers are struggling with it. For reference you can refer my [Application](https://github.com/protocol10/ASplayer/blob/master/src/com/akshay/protocol10/asplayer/MainActivity.java).

Create the **Navigation Drawer** with the standard procedure and just integrate the above library.
Hope it helps

Comment: Actually on importing the project on my workspace two file  library and MainActivity shows the error.

Comment: @VishwaPratap just clean the project and import the libary

Comment: sorry it's not working after the cleaning of project you provided

Comment: @VishwaPratap: whats the two file library. plz provide the name of error. eg resource not found anything

Comment: sir your main project contain Library folder and this library folder does not contain the lib folder,I don't know wheather lib is imporatnt or not ,only problem on importing the PagerSlidingTabStrip-master is it show error on main project only