# How to divide screen between two activities, to show a menu?

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I am trying to simulate an effect that I was seeing in some apps lately. Imagine a regular activity A, but when the user presses a button, for example a new activity B comes in from the left, moving A to the right. It fills all height, but 90% of the width.

So in the screen we have in the 90%, starting from left, activity B, and in the last 10% of the screen we have the first 10% of A.

This is useful to show a menu for example. How can it be done?

Are those different activities or it is made with a `ViewFlipper` or something like that? I can't find this exact example, but I can see it in many apps.

Comment: Also relevant: [Facebook lide slideout menu (Not using that library)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328895/facebook-lide-slideout-menu-not-using-that-library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at below example ..

[android-sliding-menu-demo](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo)

[image]

Comment: thanks, it is something like this...with a viewflipper as i imagined...thanks !