# Unable to create navigation drawer with handle

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, handle, slidingmenu

I know that this question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768360/draggable-drawer-with-a-handle-instead-of-action-bar-on-top-of-other-apps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884277/how-to-implement-a-drawerlayout-with-a-visible-handle) but still I am unable to create the navigation drawer with handle.

I have used the class as mentioned below ::

**DrawerHandle ::**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
public class DrawerHandle implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {
    public static final String TAG = "DrawerHandle";

    private ViewGroup mRootView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private View mHandle;
    private View mDrawer;

    private float mVerticalOffset;
    private int mGravity;
    private WindowManager mWM;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private Point mScreenDimensions = new Point();

    private OnClickListener mHandleClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mGravity)) mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mGravity);
            else mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mGravity);
        }

    };

    private OnTouchListener mHandleTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
        private long startClickTime;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    startClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startClickTime < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                        v.performClick();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            MotionEvent copy = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
            copy.setEdgeFlags(ViewDragHelper.EDGE_ALL);
            copy.setLocation(event.getRawX() + (mGravity == Gravity.LEFT || mGravity == GravityCompat.START ? -mHandle.getWidth()/2 : mHandle.getWidth() / 2), event.getRawY());
            mDrawerLayout.onTouchEvent(copy);
            copy.recycle();
            return true;
        }
    };

    private int getDrawerViewGravity(View drawerView) {
        final int gravity = ((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) drawerView.getLayoutParams()).gravity;
        return GravityCompat.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity, ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(drawerView));
    }

    private float getTranslation(float slideOffset){
        return (mGravity == GravityCompat.START || mGravity == Gravity.LEFT) ? slideOffset*mDrawer.getWidth() : -slideOffset*mDrawer.getWidth();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void updateScreenDimensions() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            mDisplay.getSize(mScreenDimensions);
        } else {
            mScreenDimensions.x = mDisplay.getWidth();
            mScreenDimensions.y = mDisplay.getHeight();
        }
    }

    private DrawerHandle(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, View drawer, int handleLayout, float handleVerticalOffset) {
        mDrawer = drawer;
        mGravity = getDrawerViewGravity(mDrawer);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mRootView = (ViewGroup)mDrawerLayout.getRootView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mDrawerLayout.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        mHandle = inflater.inflate(handleLayout, mRootView, false);
        mWM = (WindowManager) mDrawerLayout.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mDisplay = mWM.getDefaultDisplay();

        mHandle.setOnClickListener(mHandleClickListener);   
        mHandle.setOnTouchListener(mHandleTouchListener);
        mRootView.addView(mHandle, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(mHandle.getLayoutParams().width, mHandle.getLayoutParams().height, mGravity));
        setVerticalOffset(handleVerticalOffset);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
    }

    public static DrawerHandle attach(View drawer, int handleLayout, float verticalOffset) {
        if (!(drawer.getParent() instanceof DrawerLayout)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument drawer must be direct child of a DrawerLayout");
        return new DrawerHandle((DrawerLayout)drawer.getParent(), drawer, handleLayout, verticalOffset);
    }

    public static DrawerHandle attach(View drawer, int handleLayout) {
        return attach(drawer, handleLayout, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float slideOffset) {
        float translationX = getTranslation(slideOffset);
        mHandle.setTranslationX(translationX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }

    public View getView(){
        return mHandle;
    }

    public View getDrawer() {
        return mDrawer;
    }

    public void setVerticalOffset(float offset) {
        updateScreenDimensions();
        mVerticalOffset = offset;
        mHandle.setY(mVerticalOffset*mScreenDimensions.y);
    }
}
```

Still i am not able to get the desired output ::

What i have done so far ::

**MainActivity ::**

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, // host Activity
                mDrawerLayout, // DrawerLayout object
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret
                R.string.drawer_open, // "open drawer" description for
                                        // accessibility
                R.string.drawer_close // "close drawer" description for
                                        // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        float verticalOffset = 0.2f;
        View drawer = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        DrawerHandle.attach(drawer, R.layout.handle, verticalOffset);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What i have got so far ::

[image]

now when i click on the drawer handle icon i got the following error...

**Logcat ::**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.FrameLayout{5282c560 V.E..... ........ 0,0-768,1038 #7f09003d app:id/content_frame} is not a drawer
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1157)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1174)
at learn2crack.slidingnavigationdrawer.DrawerHandle$1.onClick(DrawerHandle.java:81)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at learn2crack.slidingnavigationdrawer.DrawerHandle$2.onTouch(DrawerHandle.java:99)
```

Kindly let me know your valuable suggestion.

Any link/guideance will be helpful....

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289395/what-do-you-need-to-pass-to-v4-widget-drawerlayout-isdraweropen-opendrawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put you Drawer and and other UI code inside a DrawerLayout.
Consider this example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >        

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <com.fscz.views.BounceViewPager
            android:id="@+id/content_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <com.fscz.views.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/content_indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            style="@style/link"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@color/black_transparent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/text"
            android:text="@string/collections"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            />
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The root element is an android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.
Inside there are 2 elements. A RelativeLayout and a LinearLayout.
By convention the DrawerLayout assumes, that the first element is 
the actual layout of your activity/fragment/whatever. The second element is the drawer. Not the drawer handle but the UI you drag in from the side. You add the handle via Java code.

So.. in a nutshell. You try to add the the handle to the layout - in my case a RelativeLayout, in your case a FrameLayout - and not to the drawer. In your example the drawer has the id: left_drawer

Answer (score -1):

Try this in onClick in DrawerHandle class

```
if (mDrawerlayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                    mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();
                } else {
                    mDrawerlayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                }
```

Comment: has nothing to do with it. he's trying to add the handle to the layout and not the drawer

Comment: This all was supposed to that handle click listener dude better check before rejecting answer .